# Passenger error message I can't figure out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, dreamhost

I am testing Rails 3 on DreamHost which just installed Rails 3.
I created a simple controller and it failed.

Browser shows 500 error (Internal Server Error) and the log shows the following message.

```
Could not find i18n-0.5.0 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file
detected.) (process 17951):
       from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in
`unmarshal_and_raise_errors'
       from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in
`spawn_application'
       from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in
`spawn_application'
       from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in
`spawn_application'
       from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in
`handle_spawn_application'
       from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
       from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
       from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in
`start_synchronously'
       from /dh/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61
[ pid=13245 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2010-12-24 12:13:38.287
]:
 Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application
'/home/cp_rails3/sites/rails3.codepremise.com': The spawn server has
exited unexpectedly.
 Backtrace:
    in 'virtual boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::Application::Session>
Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const
Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
    in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:523)
```

It runs fine in console (app.get "url") and also ok with "rails server".

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: You got this issue solved? Really interested since I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I totally had this problem on my MacBook!  Maybe you need to re-install i18n, and make double-sure you've got the right version for your architecture and new Ruby and Rails versions if you've recently moved away from Rails 2.  i18n ("eye-one-eight-en" not "eye-el-eight-en") is an internationalization library.

If you're using RVM, make sure i18n is included in the gemset you're currently using.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes. It was killed by DreamHost's watcher and I complained about it to DreamHost and they excluded it for me and I did 'bundle install'.

Comment: and that didn't solve your issue.  Anything new on this?  Also are you forced to use Dreamhost?

Comment: Actually I am a fan of DreamHost.^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what happens in the backend, but not guess.

log is your friend, checkout passenger's log folder and you will get some clues.

```
# passenger_installed_folder is usually: /opt/nginx  or /usr/local/nginx
$ tail <passenger_installed_folder>/logs/error.log
```